# How to approximate constant parameters of any generalized function?

Tags: neural-network

I am new to Data Science and Machine Learning.
I am trying to approximate constant parameters of any generalized not necessarily polynomial function given the input, desired output and the form of the function using neural network.
Is there any other way to do it using neural network or should I use some other technique?
For example this is one of the functions whose parameters **par6** and **par7** I am trying to approximate:

[image]

I have the values for **x** and **f2(x)**.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are general techniques around.  E.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

For your specific example, there's a [linearization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_regression#Transformation) (depending on the values that $y$ can take on):

$$
\begin{align*}
y &= \left[1+\left(\frac{x_1-x_2}{p_6}\right)^{p_7}\right]^{-1} \\
\frac1y-1 &= \left(\frac{x_1-x_2}{p_6}\right)^{p_7} \\
\frac1y-1 &= \left( \frac1{p_6}\right)^{p_7} (x_1-x_2)^{p_7} \\
\underbrace{\log\left(\frac1y-1\right)}_{y'} &= \underbrace{-p_7\log p_6}_{a} + \underbrace{p_7}_b\underbrace{\log(x_1-x_2)}_{x'}
\end{align*}$$
At this point, your original problem is expressed as a linear model.  Of course, the error terms are now skewed from what they originally might have been, and taking the logarithm won't have worked if $y\notin(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

I would try some kind of [grid search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization#Grid_search) or a [genetic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm).